# How to hide attributes if data is "NA"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

In my site, empty attributes values are displayed as NA, i need to hide what are all the attributes values are NA.

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: show us some coding or where you want to do the changes?

Comment: @H_Parekh : check my question, just now edited

Comment: @mujas : In my all products pages related attributes values, if any attributes values are NA, i need to hide.

Comment: you can use an if condition to not to show the values.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara : not working what u suggested

Comment: https://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2016/03/hide-magento-attributes-with-no-value-2.html  check this once

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara its working.

Comment: ok. i am feeling good to hear from you. i am adding answer. plz upvote and accept brother. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your attribute.phtml.

This file can be found here: `/app/design/frontend/[theme name]/[package name]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Put  your code to display attribute in an if condition like this-

```
if($_product->getYourAttribute())
{
 // your code to display attribute
}
```

or

```
if($_product->getYourAttribute() != 'any_particular_value') // for the value of attribute you don't want to display
{
 // your code to display attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this attributes by changing little bit code in your file `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`

**Code**

```
<?php if ((string)$_data['value'] !='No' and $_data['value'] !='NO' and $_data['value'] !='N/A'): ?>
                  <tr style=""border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;"">
                      <th style=""font-size:14px; padding-top:10px""  class=""label""><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['        label'])) ?></th>
                      <td class=""data""><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                  </tr>
                 <?php endif; ?>
```

Code may be change according to your theme.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/uv7qnEZ2

Comment: not working,,,,,